# Darken the whole map except a specific rectangular area

Tags: openlayers, layers, order

I want to darken the whole world map except for a specific rectangular region.

I create two layers:
a darkOverlay, and a highlightedLayer

My darkOverlay is as follows:

```
var darkOverlay = new ol.layer.Tile(
{
    opacity: 0.2,
    source: new ol.source.TileJSON(
        {url: 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox.world-black.json?secure'})
});
map.addLayer(darkOverlay);
```

For my highlighted area, I created a vector layer, in which I will later create a Rectangle feature inside of that layer:

```
var highlightedLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector()
    });
map.addLayer(highlightedLayer);
```

I want the highlightedLayer to always be on top of my darkenOverlay:

```
darkOverlay.setZIndex(0);
highlightedLayer.setZIndex(1);
```

Create a rectangle that is the "highlighted area" (i.e. the non-darkened area):

```
var source = highlightedLayer.getSource();
var geometry = new ol.geom.Polygon.fromExtent([x1, y1, x2, y2]); // some random points
var feature = new ol.Feature(geometry);
feature.setStyle(new ol.style.Style(
    {
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)' #blue  <-----------------------
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8)',
                width: 1
            }
        )
    }
));
source.addFeature(feature);
```

If I replace the 'rgba(0,0,0,0)' with 'blue', I correctly see a blue rectangle surrounded by dark overlay everywhere else.
However, I want the inside of the rectangle to have no fill at all, not even the dark overlay.
If I replace 'blue' with 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', I get the dark overlay inside of my rectangle.

How can I get the darkOverlay to NOT show up inside of my rectangle?

Comment: It appears you're just putting a transparent rectangle over the dark overlay. What you need to do is cut a hole in the overlay layer.

Comment: Is there an example of a hole in a layer? I only found: https://jsfiddle.net/geraldo/momc184o/2/  an example of a hole in a Polygon, not hole in layer.

Comment: I will try changing my darkOverlay into a layer.Vector containing a Polygon feature encompassing the entire world, then try and put a hole inside the Polygon..

Comment: check layer clipping on OL's example.http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/layer-clipping.html

Answer (score 1):

I managed to use this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/geraldo/momc184o/2/

to make a LinearRing inside of my Polygon.

```
// the dark area
var darkArea = new ol.geom.Polygon.fromExtent(ol.proj.transformExtent([-130, 50, -110, 40], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));


// the rectamgular "hole" inside the dark area
var extent = tileSets[tileSet]['map_extents']; // [x1, y1, x2, y2]
extent = ol.proj.transformExtent(extent, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
var linearRing = new ol.geom.LinearRing([
      [extent[0], extent[1]], // [x1,y1]
      [extent[0], extent[3]], // [x1,y2]
      [extent[2], extent[3]], // [x2,y2]
      [extent[2], extent[1]], // [x2,y1]
      [extent[0], extent[1]]  // [x1,y1]
]);
darkArea.appendLinearRing(linearRing);
var darkOverlayFeature = new ol.Feature(darkArea);
darkOverlayFeature.setStyle(new ol.style.Style(
{
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
     })
}));
var darkOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector(
{
    source: new ol.source.Vector({features: [darkOverlayFeature]})
});

map.addLayer(darkOverlay);
```